# Azure Script to find how long vm's have been deallocated for

Tags: azure, powershell

We have an azure subscription that auto shuts down vm's in the evening. Contractors have been assigned vm's and HR are supposed to let us know when they leave but I'm sure some have been shutdown for a very long time. So I'm wondering is it possible to search a subscription for deallocated machines and how long they have been deallocated for?

Answer (score 0):

Through the Audit logs (maximum 90 days) you can search for start/deallocated events.

`Get-AzActivityLog | select EventTimestamp, ResourceId -ExpandProperty OperationName |  Where-Object Value -eq Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action`

you can replace the `start` with `deallocated` to search for the last deallocation time.

If you combine this with a list of all machines, you can filter out which ones have not been used in a while.

The -ExpandProperty is to transfer the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.LocalizableString` into a `value`, see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22536 for more info on this